# Unable to create bean of propertyConfigurer from spring-servlet.xml

Tags: spring, tomcat

The relevant definition of file *WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml* is as the below.

```
<bean
    id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

    <constructor-arg ref="standardEncryptor" />

    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:#{systemProperties.env} jdbc_server.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:#{systemProperties.env} DBIB.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:#{systemProperties.env}smtp.properties</value>

            <value>classpath:#{systemProperties.env}templatedatabase.properties
            </value>

            <value>classpath:InstanceOrderWFEmail.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>
```

It looks like "systemProperties" is not a valid reference name for system properties. I got the error when loading the app from Tomcat as the below.

```
15-Aug-2018 15:53:26.599 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-18] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log StandardWrapper.Throwable

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

Error creating bean with name 'propertyConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]:

Initialization of bean failed;

nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException:

Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:

EL1008E: Property or field 'env' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.Properties' - maybe not public?
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of ":#{systemProperties.env}" is correct which references to JVM properties. I just need to add -Denv=<string> to get it work.